# Use user's session id number to find its number in a field with multiple numbers separated by commas

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a database setup (please see the sample image below) that shows each teacher's (tutor's) class they have created along with the teacher's id. In addition there are two other fields: **register_stud_ids** and **register_tut_ids** that can have one or more numbers in their field separated by commas.

I have no problem using the code below to get the resulting web page specific to that user based on their session login number if there is only one number in either field, but when there are two or more numbers in either field, the resulting web page is not specific to that user, it just shows the else of the if then... statements I have.

So, my question is, *how do I change the code below to get the user's session login number from the list of numbers in either the register_tut_ids field or the register_stud_ids field?*

[data table example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzZMG.png)

`if ($getrow['register_tut_ids'] == $_SESSION['ses_idno'] OR $getrow['tut_id'] == $_SESSION['ses_idno'] && $_SESSION['u_type'] == 't')`

`else if ($getrow['register_stud_ids'] == $_SESSION['ses_idno'] && $_SESSION['u_type'] =='s')`

Comment: Bad database design

Comment: Masivuye, since you are a developer can you please help this non developer understand why you wrote "Bad database design" and as a developer, how can the code be change to do what I asked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you update your Database structure to the following:

```
+----------+--------+------------+
| class_id | tut_id | student_id |
+----------+--------+------------+
|        1 |      2 |          1 |
|        1 |      2 |          2 |
|        1 |      2 |          3 |
|        2 |      2 |          4 |
+----------+--------+------------+
```

See how a specific class or tutorial can have multiple students?

This makes querying for data easy. Simply use a `WHERE` clause in your `SELECT` statement with the conditions you want to be fulfilled. If you get back a result then you have a matching record otherwise just do the `else` part.

Comment: Lucky, I see what you are saying, but wouldn't that increase the number of rows and thus over time cause a slow down?

Comment: Dont even worry about that. As they say premature optimisation is an evil (i even wont call what you are doing  an optimisation) Just make sure that you have your indexes defined correctly and you will be pleasantly surprised by how much computers in general can handle. If your application becomes popular then you will be able to scale your mysql deployment easily. The way you are doing things right now will cause more trouble in any case.

Comment: Thank you Lucky. I will definitely follow your advise.